# Split UserAgent string into its individual parts

Tags: java, string, split

I read the userAgent in my java class this way:

```
String user_agent = req.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

and got a string like that:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
```

I want split this string into this 4 strings:

- `Mozilla/5.0`
- `(Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0)`
- `Gecko/20100101`
- `Firefox/47.0`

and after that I want split the second string into 4 others:

- `Windows NT 6.1`
- `Win64`
- `x64`
- `rv:47.0`

but if I use something like that:

```
String [] array = user_agent.split(" ")
```

I will got:

- `Mozilla/5.0`
- `(Windows NT 6.1;`
- `Win64;`
- `x64;`
- `rv:47.0)`
- `Gecko/20100101`
- `Firefox/47.0`

Which besides have unwanted characters, do not help save each part separately after the split. Is there a way to split the string based on the space delimiter, ignoring what is inside the parenthesis?

Comment: If you can spell out the criteria to use - you can use regex groups to extract whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach of solution with Stream. Hope it will help.

```
    //split the first string

    String str = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0";
    String[] result1 = str.split("[\\(||\\)]");
    List<String> list0 = Arrays.stream(result1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String list1 = list0.get(list0.size()-1);
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.stream(list1.split("\\s"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list0.remove(list0.get(list0.size()-1));
    Stream.of(list0,list2).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.trim()));

    // then split second string into 4 others
    String string = "Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0";
    Arrays.stream(string.split(";"))
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.trim()));
```